# @media only screen does not work

Tags: css, mobile, media

I have to optimize the website for mobile devices. Tried to do it through @media only screen, but it did not work for me. Maybe someone knows how to put it in the code properly ?

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  background-image: url(../images/background.jpg);
  background-size: 100vw 100vh;
}
header {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 15vh;
  border-top: 0.5vmin ridge gray;
  border-right: 0.5vmin ridge gray;
  border-left: 0.5vmin ridge gray;
}
header img {
  max-height: 14vmin;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  vertical-align: center;
}
etc.
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/homepage.css">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Airinn hotel // Home</title>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <img src='images/logo.png' />etc.
```

Comment: where is your `@media`?

Comment: I tried to add it as an external stylesheet and also just put "@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){}" in css, but both options did not work..

Comment: I use "@media" all the time and find this works across the major platforms and devices - where specifically are you seeing this issue? Have you tried using "Inspect Element" within Chrome to diagnose what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it should be done (Mobile first):

```
.test {
    width: 200px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    .test {    
        width: 1000px;
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yzt9zjno/

Also, [this tutorial should help](https://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/).

Comment: It is strange, but I can add @media only in this way.. by some reason it does not work if I add media screen and (min-width:1024px){} at the top of css

Comment: Media should be AFTER your other CSS code. Check this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yzt9zjno/ Try to resize result window.

Comment: okay, thank you ! also , maybe you know how to write a comparison between the width and length ? for example, by standart width is two times more than length (2:1). If the width is less than 2, @media should start to work.

Comment: Maybe you mean Height?

Comment: oh yea, height.. sorry

Comment: but can I set something like (min-width:2x) and (min-height:1x) ??

Comment: Sorry, but no. You can calculate this ratio only in JS.
In CSS, you may only set numbers, not dependecies.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try having several css ?
The first one, global(homepage.css) and one for each kind of support ?

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/homepage.css" />
<!-- Now for "normal" screens" -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css" media="screen" />
<!-- And for mobiles / small screens -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/small.css" media="handheld" />
```

the @media doesn't need the "only", it will be read only by the matching media

Comment: what is the point of adding for "normal" screens if homepage.css is supposed to be for normal screens ? the problem is that my navigation bar crashes when the width of a screen is becoming less than 2:1 comparing to the height, I just need to fix this

Comment: Sorry, I didn't fully understood your trouble. Forget my participation.